# Why was a solaris question closed?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, moderation

can someone clarify why [CRS error working with Solaris](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346232/crs-error-working-with-solaris/346299#346299) was closed as off-topic?

It is asking about the [solaris python library for geospatial analysis](https://github.com/cosmiq/solaris) and is asking a specific question about a bug/problem the user encountered when working with the module. This seems on-topic for GIS Stack Exchange to me, but I could be misunderstanding the intended scope of the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Questions that relate to the business of vendors and product teams,
>   such as **licensing**, **pricing**, **release dates**, **submission of bug reports**
>   and **enhancement requests**, *etc*, are off-topic here and should be
>   directed instead to the official software support teams.

You have said this is a bug and that you are a maintainer of the project, and have directed the asker to post the bug report on the github repo.  Therefore it's off-topic here

Answer (score 1):

The vote to close on that question came from a moderator other than I, but I agree with it.

The reason is your answer there:

> I'm one of the maintainers for the solaris project. I tried to
>   reproduce your error in my environment but could not.
>
> If you open an issue in [the solaris github
>   repo](https://github.com/cosmiq/solaris) with the full traceback, and
>   your python/solaris/pyproj/fiona versions, then we would be happy to
>   try to figure out what's going on.

You, as one of the maintainers for the solaris project, have said that it is appropriate to submit as a bug to the solaris GitHub, and we have a custom close reason here (the one that was used) for closing such questions.

I think that custom close reason was last discussed here at [Adding 'bug reports' to off-topic close reasons dialog?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4977/115)